# A way to type only upper case in this cin input

Tags: c++, format, uppercase

So I want to know if there's a way that when we type in console. It'll only be uppercase.

Like this example.

from this

> Your input : asda

should be this when we typing.

> Your input : ASDA

here is my code

`cout << "Type Memory Adress (in hexadecimal) = 0x";
  cin >> hex >> memoryAdress;`

Comment: As opposed to... reading whatever was typed and *converting* it to upper case?  The condition "when we typing" suggests you want the terminal to transmorph whatever-to-upper-case on the fly, and that isn't happening without non-standard hooks into your IO system (ncurses *may* be able to do this; i've honestly never tried).

Comment: @WhozCraig: Yes, you are right. With ncurses it is easy to achieve. Im using ncurses now and then on an RPi and it works quite well.

Comment: so in standard library this can't be done right?

Answer (score 0):

In C++, isupper() and islower() are predefined functions used for string and character handling.cstring.h is the header file required for string functions and cctype.h is the headerfile required for character functions.

Comment: @mysteriousRyu wanted the input screen automatically display uppercase, as user start typing

Comment: @KanishkTanwar So he want uppercase in console ?

Comment: @MohammadYasir Thanks for answer. and yeah I just want to know if there's a way to uppercase in console.